# Is that possible for a system to have infinitely many equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

For some system, when solving the equilibrium, some variable vanished and has no effect on finding the equilibrium, for example.
$$x' = \frac{y}{x}$$
$$y' = y$$
$$z' = z+y - 4$$
So for this system, if we solve the equilibrium point, $y$ must equal to $0$ and therefore the first equation just equal to zero for all $x$.

So in the cases, can we say, the equilibrium is $(x, 0, 4) $ for all $x$ value?

Comment: Yes, although some of the classical theory for local analysis of equilibria breaks down in this situation.

Comment: (Also the case of starting at $(0,0,z_0)$ is fishy.)